# Why Sequenial Equilibrium (SE) imposes no restrictions on the off-equilibrium beliefs in the Spence's model?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, dynamic-games, equilibrium-selection

I read some lectures on the Spence's model. Some (see e.g. P31 of [lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-16-strategy-and-information-spring-2016/lecture-slides/MIT14_16S16_equilib_refine.pdf) PPT from MIT game thoery course) mention that SE imposes no restrictions on the off-equilibrium beliefs but without proof. I am wondering how they get that result because to me, I think verifying an equilibrium in the Spence model is an SE should be difficult since the message space of the worker is continuous.

Comment: I guess the statement refers to a version of Spence's model with discrete effort levels, at least by analogy. There simply is no sequential equilibrium as usually defined with a continuum of possible effort levels.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker Oh, that means if we denote the equilibrium education level sent by the worker in a pooling equilibrium as $e^{*}$, then the message space of the worker in that pooling can be viewed as $\{ e^{*}, \text{not}\, e^{*} \}$, right?

Comment: You can allow more levels, but only finitely many.

Comment: @Michael Greinecker Do you know any formal references or examples about discretizing the action space in signaling games? Thanks.

Comment: None comes to mind, but I'm sure I have seen it in some textbooks before. The argument why there is no additional restriction on off equilibrium beliefs is not that hard though.